# Show a different template after two days in php with date()

Tags: php

I have this code to capture a date and time:

```
date('F j, Y, g:i a T')
```

and save is as

```
$datetime:
```

and I have this code to include a template:

```
function template_contents($file, $model) {
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        throw new Exception("Template not found");
    }
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    $contents2 = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $contents;
}

if($datetime == "No Date Yet"){
    echo template_contents("post.php", $model);
} elseif($datetime == "June 2, 2010, 2:55 pm MDT"){
    echo template_contents("notpost.php", $model);
}else {
    echo template_contents("post.php", $model);
}
```

And I as hoping to edit the elseif statement to show the notpost.php template if the $datetime  was less than 2 days.  So, notpost.php shows up for two days and post.php shows up after two days.

Comment: Is this to be a automated process, your the control date is hard coded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the elseif statement to:

```
} elseif (time() <= strtotime("June 2, 2010, 2:55 pm MDT")) {
```

This shows notpost.php if the current time (given by `time()`) is earlier than the given time.